# Error while calling function from procedure from same package

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to oracle.I have created a package which has spec and body.

It's header is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE OT.PK_TEST IS
FUNCTION PRNT_STRNG RETURN VARCHAR2;
PROCEDURE PR_SUPERHERO(F_NAME VARCHAR2,L_NAME VARCHAR2);
END PK_TEST;
/
```

Its body is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY OT.PK_TEST IS
FUNCTION PRNT_STRNG 
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
RETURN 'ASHWIN';
END PRNT_STRNG;
PROCEDURE PR_SUPERHERO(F_NAME VARCHAR2,L_NAME VARCHAR2) 
IS
BEGIN
OT.PK_TEST.PRNT_STRNG;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(F_NAME);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_NAME);
END PR_SUPERHERO;
END PK_TEST;
/
```

I wanted to test the whether the function can be called from body of procedure or not.So,I added:

```
OT.PK_TEST.PRNT_STRNG;
```

to call the function which is returning varchar.But,I got error:

```
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
11/1    PLS-00221: 'PRNT_STRNG' is not a procedure or is undefined
11/1    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
 (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

Can i call function from the procedure of same package or not? Also,can i call function of different package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling a function would return an output. You need to assign the function to a variable like:

```
some_var = OT.PK_TEST.PRNT_STRNG;
```

You can only call procedures directly

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call the function/procedure in the same package. You can also call other function from other package or other schema, you just have to reference it. The only thing you are missing is assigning a variable to the return of the function you have called.

You should do it like this:

```
v_temp VARCHAR2(32 CHAR);

BEGIN
    v_temp := OT.PK_TEST.PRNT_STRNG;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_temp );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(F_NAME);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_NAME);
END PR_SUPERHERO;
```